# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в поздравлении?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> С Новым Годом Свиньи!

Как правильно расставить знаки препинания в этом поздравлении? :)

Comment: Всех поздравляю с наступающим Новым годом!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вместо верной и дружелюбной Собаки, хозяйки 2018 года, приходит Желтая земляная Свинья — позитивное, общительное животное (если верить китайскому гороскопу).

1. С Новым Годом, Сви́ньи!
   Обращение к тем, кто родился в год свиньи (или Свиньи).
2. С Новым Годом Свиньи́!
   В последний раз год Свиньи был в 2007-м. Прошло двенадцать лет, поэтому сегодня, как мне кажется, можно так сказать: Сви́ньи, с Новым Годом Свиньи́!

У С. Маршака ("Хор Поросят"):
Я — свинья, и ты — свинья,
Все мы, братцы, свиньи.

Две мои подруги, родившиеся в год Свиньи, в день рождения обращаются друг к другу именно так, подразумевая, конечно, заглавную **С**.

Comment: Ответ превзошел мои ожидания и добавил новогоднего позитива! С Новым годом, Римма Михайлова!

Comment: Спасибо. Пожелания здоровья и праздничного настроения — Вам и всем-всем!